# Matplotlib - disable gradience?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data, and I'd like to have different colors based on category. I have 3 categories, 0, 1 and 2. One of the axes is this category, but I'd also like to color it. I'm doing:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 8))
plt.clf()
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)    

ax.set_xlabel("Assignee")
ax.set_ylabel("Cluster")
ax.set_zlabel("Time")

ax.scatter(df.assigned_to, df.cluster, df.resolution_time, c=df.cluster, edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

This however, still gives me gradients within category:

[image]

How do I make sure that each dot in the same cluster gets the same color, no gradience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it helps to read the documentation. The 3D [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) has an argument

> `depthshade`
>       Whether or not to shade the scatter markers to give the appearance of depth. Default is True.

You may set it to `False` to get rid of the shading.

```
ax.scatter(... , depthshade=False)
```